# Angular 2 effect doesn't run do function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I got this effect:

```
@Effect() createModel$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(CREATE_MODEL_REQUEST)
  .switchMap(action => this.modelsApi.createModel(action.payload)
    .do(() => ({type: CREATE_MODEL_SUCCESS}))
    .map(() => ({type: GET_MODELS_REQUEST}))
    .catch((err: any) => Observable.of({type: REQUEST_FAILURE, payload: err})));
```

And I'm trying to dispatch a success action to my `http` reducer which decreases an `activeRequests` counter if the request is successful. And the `.map` after it should trigger a new get request that fetches a new list of models from the api.

The problem is that no matter what I do, I can't get both of `CREATE_MODEL_SUCCESS` and `GET_MODELS_REQUEST` to run no matter what I seem to try.

How can I make sure that both are run if the initial call of the `createModel`function is successful?

**EDIT:** It does actually seem like the `.do` is run because if I replace it with a `console.log(true)` I can see that it runs, but it doesn't dispatch the `({type: CREATE_MODEL_SUCCESS})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `do` function does not do anything:

```
.do(() => ({type: CREATE_MODEL_SUCCESS}))
```

It attempts to return a value, but the return value will be ignored - so nothing happens. The `do` operator cannot be used to emit a different value from the observable, which is what you are attempting to do.

Note that if you were to put `console.log` call into your `do`, you should see it writing to the console.

If you want to emit multiple actions, you can use something like this:

```
@Effect() createModel$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(CREATE_MODEL_REQUEST)
  .switchMap(action => this.modelsApi.createModel(action.payload))
  .concatMap(() => Observable.from([
    { type: CREATE_MODEL_SUCCESS },
    { type: GET_MODELS_REQUEST }
  ]))
  .catch((err: any) => Observable.of({ type: REQUEST_FAILURE, payload: err }));
```

Comment: So the solution is.. what?

Comment: Nice, it works. Could you explain more in depth what's happening? Trying so hard to understand the rxjs methods but hard to find decent explanations.

Comment: `switchMap` switches what's emitted from the source observable to what's emitted from the returned observable and the returned observable emits the two actions - `Observable.from` emits the values in the array that it's passed one after the other. The actions then flow from the effect and are distpached by the store, etc.

Comment: Actually, given that the returned observable immediately emits the actions and then completes, `concatMap` is probably a better choice; `switchMap` is overkill.